# Want to open Word, Excel & PowerPoint files in application

Tags: android, excel, ms-access, ms-word

I am developing an Android application which will open Word & excel file. Does anyone done similar before. Please provide some links or demos.

In Iphone if we give path for doc file or xls file to UIWebView it opens it. But it doesn't work in Android. So does any one know way to do this.

Thank You.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The application `Polaris Office` is installed on my Samsung Galaxy S 2 by the carrier. And does just that (+ powerpoint).

https://www.infraware.co.kr/eng/01_product/product17.asp

Comment: Pim Reijersen-------Thanks for reply but I am looking any open source help to develop such application.